# Where to find documentation for definitions for AVR programming in C

Tags: avr, avr-gcc

I wonder if there is a documentation for AVR (I am using C to program) definitions like `PIN5_bm` or `SLEEP_MODE_PWR_DOWN`, or if I just have the information given in the respective header file. I tried to find this kind of information in the [datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/ATmega4808-4809-Data-Sheet-DS40002173A.pdf) of the AVR chip (and elsewhere), but without success. I would like know where to look for such definitions, to find new useful ones.

Comment: Those definitions would be found in the header files you include with your C program.

Comment: The header file is the answer. Also try to read this https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/Appnotes/AVR1000b-Getting-Started-Writing-C-Code-for-AVR-DS90003262B.pdf

Comment: Usually these are available as "application notes" and also in compiler document.

Comment: The avr-libc has good online documentation. Did you read there?

Comment: Are you looking for what they *are*, or what they *do*?  Those definitions are all bare-metal register and bit descriptions; to know what they *do* look in the microcontrollers user's manual.

Comment: https://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/modules.html

Comment: @G36 Thanks, exactly what I was looking for. If you want you can post it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2):

When you program in C, you are using a compiler and library provided by someone. The two most common ones are avr-libc https://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/modules.html and Atmel studio https://www.microchip.com/en-us/development-tools-tools-and-software/gcc-compilers-avr-and-arm.

The documentation there should be what you are looking for. For the most part, registers follow the naming convention on the datasheet, but functions need some explanation.

Answer (score 1):

> I tried to find this kind of information in the datasheet of the AVR chip (and elsewhere)

Most of the defines are provided by AVR-LibC, the C library that avr-gcc is using.  The naming convention tries to relate to names used in the data sheets, but sometimes AVR-LibC uses own names, which may have several reasons<sup>1</sup>.

The main question is how to find the definitions and which name are used in the headers. Perhaps the easiest way is to open the respective header file as text file or use tools like `grep` to find stuff.  Today, each group of defines is prededed by a comment that related the macros to the SFR with respective bitfields, like this snip from ATtiny204's `iotn204.h` located in `avr/include/avr/`:

```
/* ADC.CTRLB  bit masks and bit positions */
#define ADC_SAMPNUM_gm  0x07  /* Accumulation Samples group mask. */
#define ADC_SAMPNUM_gp  0  /* Accumulation Samples group position. */
#define ADC_SAMPNUM0_bm  (1<<0)  /* Accumulation Samples bit 0 mask. */
#define ADC_SAMPNUM0_bp  0  /* Accumulation Samples bit 0 position. */
#define ADC_SAMPNUM1_bm  (1<<1)  /* Accumulation Samples bit 1 mask. */
#define ADC_SAMPNUM1_bp  1  /* Accumulation Samples bit 1 position. */
#define ADC_SAMPNUM2_bm  (1<<2)  /* Accumulation Samples bit 2 mask. */
#define ADC_SAMPNUM2_bp  2  /* Accumulation Samples bit 2 position. */
```

The lower-case suffixes are:
| Suffix | Meaning | Range
|------|--------|----|
| `_bm` | Bit Mask | A power of 2
| `_bp` | Bit Position | 0 to 7
| `_gm` | Group Mask | Sequence of `1`'s in binary representation
| `_gp` | Group Position | 0 to 7
| `_gc` | Group Constant | A value that can be used to set a group,
 already shiftet to the right position in the target byte (at `_gp`) |

The naming convention AVR-LibC is using to name the headerfile is quite cumbersome. You can also extract the defines from a pre-processed C file so you need not search the file. Just one example to find ADC related stuff:

```
> echo "#include <avr/io.h>" | avr-gcc -mmcu=atmega328 -xc - -E -dM | grep ADC
#define ADC_vect _VECTOR(21)
#define ADC _SFR_MEM16(0x78
...
```

avr-gcc compiles the file `#include <avr/io.h>` provided by `echo` which it reads from stdin as of `-`. Because the file has no extension, we have to provide the file type *"C file"* by means of `-xc` prior to specifying the file. `-E` means *"preprocess only"*, and `-dM` means *"print all macro definitions"*.

---

<sup>1</sup>Like harware supplier provides hardware description that's not aligned with the data sheets / has typos, and it's too much pain to maintain fixes in AVR-LibC.

Comment: It could also be any other compiler, other than avr-gcc, which comes with some compiler vendor libraries, other than avr-libc. There's plenty of C compilers for AVR. Codevision, Imagecraft, Rowley Crossworks, IAR,  etc.

Comment: @Justme: As the question is tagged [avr-gcc], I assumed that avr-gcc is a reasonable assumption. No?